# Does AWS ELB support RFC-5746 when configured for HTTPS

Tags: https, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Is it possible to configure AWS ELB for HTTPS access in such a way as to support RFC-5746 (TLS Renegotiation Indication Extension)? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

See this thread [disable client-initiated renegotiation](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=93915) and this one [is ELB vulnerable to BEAST attack](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=376441&#376441)

The basics of those posts are: No, not with ELB termination of SSL. You need to pass through SSL connections to an instance where you can configure SSL as per requirements.

I am not sure if those posts are still applicable though. I have dealt with McAfee and run a scan against a default ELB policy configuration minus CBC ciphers, and their scans pass PCI compliance.